# Use react navigation TabNavigation in clojurescript

Tags: react-navigation, clojurescript, reagent

I have some problems in using a HeadTitle with ClojureScript:
- What's the working mechanism of `navigationOPtions`?
- How can I write a interoptions UI with TabNavigation and HeadTile?
- Can reagent do some works to reach the HeadTitle?

This is an official example:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      header: "Hello",
    };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home'
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: HomeStack,
    navigationOptions:({naviagtion}) => ({
      tabBarLabel: 'home'
    })
  },
  DetailsScreen: {
    screen: DetailsScreen,
    navigationOptions:({naviagtion}) => ({
      tabBarLabel: 'detail'
    })
  }
}

const Appcontainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Appcontainer />
  );
}
```

How can do it in ClojureScript? I hava try it using `reagent/create-class`, but not work. What should I do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you are working with, but it looks like when it comes down to it, you are trying to use a React component in Reagent. Have you read this? https://reagent-project.github.io/docs/master/InteropWithReact.html. In particular in this case I'd probably use `reagent/adapt-react-class`.

Comment: There's a good example for your case in this section of the docs: https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/InteropWithReact.md#creating-reagent-components-from-react-components

Comment: Ok, I have resolve it.

Comment: @BeibeiKang please add an answer showing how you resolved the problem.